# Can we estimate $P(x)$ using $P(1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, estimation

Given a polynomial $P(x)$, is it possible to estimate/lower bound/upper bound the value of $P(k)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ if we know $P(1)$?

We can also assume $P(x)$ has only natural coefficients and is only taken over $x \in \mathbb{N}$ if that helps.

Comment: If all coefficients are natural then $P(k) \ge P(1)$. For $k>1$, no upper bound exists since the sequence $P_i(k) = P(1)*k^i$ is infinitely large.

Comment: If, by *natural* coefficients you mean positive integers and no minus signs, then, *yes* perhaps a lower bound. Not an upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

No if you assume that the coefficients can be in $\mathbb{Z}$, as you can just consider for example the family 
$$P_n(x)=(x-1)^n$$
You clearly have no control whatsoever on the growth rate, but all share the same value $$P_n(1)=0$$

In the case of positive integers, you too cannot find any upper bound, as the family of monomials
$$P_n(x)=x^n$$
have similar properties as the one we said above, but for any polynomial $P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i$with positive coefficiens, it holds that
$$P(x)\ge P(1),\quad\forall x\ge 1$$
because $x^i\ge 1 $ if $x\ge 1$ and so
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ix^i\ge \sum_{i=1}^na_i(1)^i=\sum_{i=1}^na_i=P(1)$$
Where the positivity of the coefficients is needed to pass from $x^i\ge 1$ to $a_ix^i\ge a_i(1)^i$.